# Need simple HTML on a Google Form

Tags: html, google-forms

I need a bit of your help. 
This is probably a very simple question.

I have an html code from my Google form which I copied manually.

I pasted it into my GAS function to open and fill out the form inside a Google Sheet.

The issue is that **the Submit button is not active (not Submitting the form)**.

What's the easiest solution for it?

Here the html:

```html
<div role="button" type="submit" class="quantumWizButtonEl quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonEl quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonFlat quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonDark quantumWizButtonPaperbutton2El2 freebirdFormviewerViewNavigationSubmitButton isUndragged" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow jsname="M2UYVd" tabindex="0" >
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No console errors. Button just doesn't Submit

Comment: I can add my own button, but it's good to know how to modify a native form. Can someone help on that?